Associtivity of Tensor Product of Modules Over Algebras in a Tensor Category
I am attempting to prove that modules over a commutative algebra (monoid) $A$ in a fixed tensor category $\mathcal{T}$ form a tensor category $\mathcal{T}_A$. All of the references I have found say it is a straight forward generalization of the proof when $\mathcal{T}=\text{Ab}$ but I have found it not so straight forward. The tensor product of modules $M$ and $N$, denoted $M\otimes_A N$ is defined as the coequalizer of the two natural maps from $M\otimes A\otimes N$ to $M\otimes N$ where $\otimes$ is the tensor product in $\mathcal{T}$. I have shown that $\mathcal{T}_A$ is an abelian category and that $M\otimes_A N$ is a module. Proving associativity of the tensor product has been more difficult.
From here on out fix $A$-modules $M$, $N$, and $P$. Let $p:M\times N\to M\otimes_A N$ and $q:N\otimes P\to N\otimes_A P$ be the coequalizers defining the tensor products. Let $r_1$,$r_2$,$r_3$ be the right multiplication maps for $N$, $M$, and $M\otimes_A N$, respectively. Let $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, and $\ell_3$ be the left multiplication maps for $N$, $P$, and $N\otimes_A P$ respectively. We know there is an isomorphism $$a:(M\otimes A\otimes N)\otimes N\otimes P\to M\otimes A\otimes (N\otimes A\otimes P).$$ I am trying to induce an isomorphism $\alpha:(M\otimes_A N)\to M\otimes_A (N\otimes_A P)$. I'm trying to do that using this commutative diagram. Clearly each row reduces to a coequalizer of four maps. These are
\begin{align*}
f_1&=(p\circ(\text{Id}_M\otimes\ell_1))\otimes\ell_2\\
f_2&=(p\circ(r_2\otimes\text{Id}_N))\otimes\ell_2\\
f_3&=((r_3\circ((p\circ(r_2\otimes\text{Id}_N))\otimes\text{Id}_A)\otimes\text{Id}_P\\
f_4&=((r_3\circ((p\circ(r_2\otimes\text{Id}_N))\otimes\text{Id}_A))\otimes\text{Id}_P
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
g_1&=\text{Id}_M\otimes((\ell_3\circ(\text{Id}_A\otimes(q\circ(r_1\otimes\text{Id}_P))))\\
g_2&=\text{Id}_M\otimes((\ell_3\circ(\text{Id}_A\otimes(q\circ(\text{Id}\otimes\ell_2))))\\
g_3&=r_2\otimes(q\circ(r_1\otimes\text{Id}_P))\\
g_4&=r_2\otimes(q\circ(\text{Id}_N\otimes\ell_2))
\end{align*}
From here I was hoping to use the univeral property of coequalizers to deduce the isomorphism $\alpha$ but that doesn't quite apply yet. You would need to find maps $$\phi:(M\otimes_A N)\otimes P\to\text{coeq}(g_i)$$
and
$$\psi:M\otimes(N\otimes_A P)\to\text{coeq}(f_i)$$
that ideally involve $a$ in a way and satisfy the universal property of coequalizers. Then we show the resulting unique maps are inverse of eachother. But this is where I'm stuck. I've tried assuming the maps existed and computing them, but that method has been ineffective.

I believe a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of the associators is that $M\otimes_A-$ and $-\otimes_A P$ preserve the coequalizer forks $N\otimes A\otimes P\rightrightarrows N\otimes P\to N\otimes_A P$ and $M\otimes A\otimes N\rightrightarrows M\otimes N\to M\otimes_A N$.
